# Kendo Tree View drag and drop with out loosing its source

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

i am using Kendo UI Tree for the purpose of drag and drop between two trees.

i am filling it using ajax call.

now the issue is i can find the source and destination of the node when i moved any item from TreeViewA to itself but when i drag and drop item from TreeViewA to TreeViewB i can't find source and destination nodes ids.

Please Help!

Plus can i drag and drop source item copy not removing node from the source.

Comment: hey @Syeda look at [drag and drop without remove item source](http://www.telerik.com/forums/re-two-trees----allowing-the-drop-but-preventing-the-draggable-from-moving#2z382UEs3ke97ZvdV5MOyg) from Telerik Forums

Answer (score 2):

When you have two trees, you can get access to the nodes and their data in the following way (defining the drop function):

```
, drop: function (e) {
    if (e.valid) {
    var theOtherTree = $(e.dropTarget).parents('.k-treeview').data("kendoTreeView");
    console.log('drop source: ' + this.dataItem(e.sourceNode).customData);
    console.log('drop target: ' + theOtherTree.dataItem(e.dropTarget).customData);
    }
}
```

- "this" refers to the source tree, and the target tree is obtained through the dropTarget
- you can retrieve id, or whatever custom data in the node you want.